# Is there a way to write the PL/SQL code of select...INTO.. query in Java

Tags: java, plsql

I am converting the PL/SQL code to Java code to get rid of the DB dependency. In PL/SQL we have something like this.

```
SELECT Status_Code, ERROR_CODE, Error_Message
          INTO I_Status_Code, I_Error_Code, I_Error_Message
          FROM T_Parent_Lots_Api
         WHERE Transaction_Id = I_Transaction_Id;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN No_Data_Found THEN
      I_Status_Code   := Failure_Code;
      I_Error_Code    := SQLCODE;
      I_Error_Message := 'Error for transaction id -' || I_Transaction_Id ||
                         '- in tlotutils.t_update_txn_status-' || SQLERRM;
      RETURN;
```

Seems we cannot run the above SQL query in Java due to the `INTO` keyword. I can write the catch block to handle exception. I can remove the `INTO` keyword and execute the query and assign them from the `ResultSet` but the challenge here is if the select query is not returning any data then the relative java code `SQLException.getErrorCode()` & `SQLException.getSQLState` for `SQLCODE` & `SQLERRM` functions are returning empty

Comment: You use `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` to run that query **without** the INTO clause, then iterate over the `ResultSet` and store the values in Java variables. Pretty much the most basic thing you can do in JDBC. `ResultSet.next()` will tell you if the query returned anything

Comment: Yes @ a_horse_with_no_name , but SQLException.getErrorCode() will return empty if the resultset is empty and  if we run the query in the PLSQL it will give the error code bcoz there is no data to insert into variables

Comment: So what? You can still check if the result is empty in Java. Just in a different way